# puppeteer form submit: evaluate is not a function

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

the form exists in the page and i am sure.

```
const form = await page.$('#my-form');
await form.evaluate(form => form.submit());
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: form.evaluate is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2019: As mentioned by Kyle, the latest puppeteer have [.evaluate method on elementHandle](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleevaluatepagefunction-args). It's been two years after all.

```
const tweetHandle = await page.$('.tweet .retweets');
expect(await tweetHandle.evaluate(node => node.innerText)).toBe('10');
```

---

You can try it this way,

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
 const element = document.querySelector("#my-form")
 element.submit()
});
```

`ElementHandle` does not have a `.evaluate` function property. Check the [docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle).

Comment: Looks like it's supposed to? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleevaluatepagefunction-args

Comment: The answer is 2 years old. The API must've changed since then. :)

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For new comers, if you encounter this problem. You're probably using `puppeteer 1.19` or lower and need to update `npm update puppeteer`. Use the [API](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md) of your version (see links at the top of the page by version).

Answer (score 0):

> the form exists in the page and i am sure

How are you sure? If you're verifying the form's presence by looking at the developer tools, that's no guarantee that the element wasn't added dynamically via JS after the `page.$` call runs. `view-source:` is the place to look for statically-present elements (and when JS runs, some of those elements may be changed or removed, so it's also no guarantee of an element's presence once JS starts executing).

`page.$` does not wait for the element to appear, so if you're using it immediately after a navigation, it may well fail. The solution is typically `page.waitForSelector`. In your case,

```js
const form = await page.waitForSelector('#my-form');
await form.evaluate(form => form.submit());
```

If this times out, then there may be a typo in your selector, the element may be in an iframe or shadow root, or the page may be blocking you. Without a reproducible example, it's anyone's guess.